1TB SDD exFAT Data Drive shows as unallocated free space after booting into Win10
Had a 1TB SSD drive formatted to exFAT solely for storing data: documents, photos, videos, music. I have LM22 and Win10 on two separate other SSD drives.
For the first time in a long time, and the first time since I had this drive installed, I booted into Windows. Now that I've booted back into Mint, the drive shows as free space with no partitions. GParted says the same
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
[sudo] password for chris:
Disk /dev/sdc: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: EDILOCA ES106 1T
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6b8178f0

lsblk -e 7 -o name,type,fstype,size,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,label,mountpoint
<snip>
sdc disk 953.9G
<snip>

System:
Host: Goliath Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma
Machine:
Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: H110M-A v: N/A
serial: <superuser required>
Mobo: Gigabyte model: H110M-A-CF v: x.x serial: <superuser required>
UEFI: American Megatrends v: F20 date: 11/08/2016
Drives:
Local Storage: total: 3.99 TiB used: 1.34 TiB (33.7%)
ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37120G size: 111.79 GiB
ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: PNY model: CS900 240GB SSD size: 223.57 GiB
ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Ediloca model: ES106 1TB MX size: 953.87 GiB
ID-4: /dev/sde vendor: Western Digital model: WD30NMZW-11GX6S1
size: 2.73 TiB type: USB
Unmounted:
ID-1: /dev/sda1 size: 499 MiB fs: ntfs
ID-2: /dev/sda3 size: 16 MiB fs: <superuser required>
ID-3: /dev/sda4 size: 111.19 GiB fs: ntfs
ID-4: /dev/sdb2 size: 512 MiB fs: vfat

Booting back into Windows, it doesn't show up as a drive, just a device. I've fully shut down windows and boot back into Mint and the drive still shows as unallocated free space.
I have no idea what happened, but how do I get my data back?

Did you tried to access the problematic drive while in Windows? If so what happened, exactly? Do you remember any message showing up regarding the partition that's now gone?

I did not try to access the drive while in Windows the first time.
